# Jetty deployment error

Tags: deployment, jetty, eclipse-wtp

I have deployed a project in Jetty (jetty-wtp plugin) in an Eclipse "Server". When I start the Jetty server the console output an error:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/security/RunAs`

I also added `common-annotations.jar` to this project lib but cann't resolve this problem.

My installed environment:

- JDK 1.6.0
- jetty 8.0.0.M2
- jetty-wtp http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-wtp/development

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[download  annotations-api.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadannotationsapijar.htm)

download and include the above jar in your classpath

Comment: what would be the Maven dependency for this? so that it wouldn't have to be downloaded and put under `lib` manually. (this is probably common knowledge for experienced Java developers but somewhat a stumbing point for rookies)

Comment: ...I think that's: `javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2` (`"javax.annotation" % "javax.annotation-api" % "1.2"` for SBT).

Answer (score 2):

(Inspired from http://pipecuts.wordpress.com/2011/01/30/classnotfoundexception-org-objectweb-asm-classvisitor/#comment-18)

- In the Servers view, right-click the entry for your (Jetty) server and select "Open".
- Click the link 'Open launch configuration' and select the 'Classpath' tab in the resulting dialog box.
- Select the 'User Entries' section and click 'Add External JARs'. Point it to jetty/lib/annotations/javax.annotation-*[version]*.jar.

I'm using Jetty 8.1.1.v20120215 with Eclipse Indigo SR1 (WTP 3.3.2, Jetty WTP Adaptor 1.0)